# Why does a clean yarn install delete modules from yarn.lock?

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

In a React Native project: when I delete everything in my node_modules directory, then run yarn v 1.22 against my yarn.lock, modules are deleted from the text of yarn.lock and, consequently, my node_modules install is incomplete.

This is inconvenient when the yarn.lock is committed, then another developer does a pull, tries to run yarn, and gets the results I described.

Is there a way to run yarn so that all files in the module are installed, and nothing is deleted from yarn.lock?

Comment: Strange... This happens every time?

Comment: yes. good--it IS strange, right?

Comment: https://mattbatman.com/on-occasion-my-yarn-lockfile-is-the-problem It seems like there are dependencies on package.json! I thought yarn ignored package.json.

Comment: Yarn installs the dependencies in your package.json, thats the purpose of it?

Comment: I just realized this. Thanks. I thought it had its own files. I'm a little stunned that it requires on a file generated by another tool.